# How do I crop a photo without spinning it

Tags: photos

[image]

On this screen in the stock **Gallery** app on the Note 5, I always try to crop by dragging a corner inward, and most of the time it **spins** the photo instead. I hate that! How do I make it clear that I want to crop, not spin?!

Comment: What is this app? Please edit and make it clear.

Comment: Stock Gallery app

Comment: Which device and Android version is it? That which is a stock Gallery app to Samsung or Sony  may not necessarily be a stock Gallery for Nexus or Pixel owners.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 5

Answer (score 0):

Tap on “Ratio” button and it will give you options like: “1:1, 4:3, 16:9 and free”. At that point you will be in crop mode. Select an aspect ratio from that list and then drag the corners to crop the image. The Image showing is 16:9. Tap “free” to crop to any ratio that pleases you.